# pandas, find for each column all the rows with True elements

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this:

```
      A      B     C     D
0  True  False  True  False
1  True  False  True  False
2  True   True  True  False
```

Without using for loops, I want to find a way of getting back for each column in which indexes are true.

So something like (A:[1,2,3], B:[2], C:[1,2,3], D:[]).
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion here is better use dict comprehension:

```
d = {c: df.index[df[c]].tolist() for c in df.columns}
print (d)
{'A': [0, 1, 2], 'B': [2], 'C': [0, 1, 2], 'D': []}
```

Pandas solution is more complicated:

```
#apply are still loops under the hood
d = df.apply(lambda x: x.index[x].tolist()).to_dict()
print (d)
{'A': [0, 1, 2], 'B': [2], 'C': [0, 1, 2], 'D': []}
```

---

```
s = df.stack()

d = (s[s].reset_index()
         .groupby('level_1')['level_0']
         .agg(list).reindex(df.columns, fill_value=[])
         .to_dict())
print (d)
{'A': [0, 1, 2], 'B': [2], 'C': [0, 1, 2], 'D': []}
```